# SSH - Linux to Windows Server 2016

Tags: windows, server

We installed OpenSSH using github on a Windows Server 2016.  Everything works great except passwordless login.  Here's the scenario:

Domain-joined CentOS server trying to SSH into Domain-joined Windows Server 2016 with OpenSSH using domain credentials.

On Centos server:
log in with domain user "user"
ssh-keygen -t rsa
key saved in /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa

On Windows Server
Copy id_rsa.pub entry from Centos server into "authorized_keys" file for user on Windows box (C:\Users\User\.ssh\authorized_keys).  Save the file.

On Centos Server:
while logged in as domain user "user"
ssh user@WindowsServer
accept into known_hosts
get prompted for password

In theory, we shouldn't get prompted for a password, but we do.  Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have any error messages? Have you tried to remove public key from Windows machine and check if it changes anything? BTW: Does password login work fine?

Comment: Yes, password login works fine.  I didn't see any meaningful logs on the Windows side.  I have not tried removing the public key from the Windows box.

Comment: Did you just miss '\' here or you actually use directory with name "User.ssh"?

Comment: Missed it when i typed it...i corrected it